# Intellij IDEA: show implied iterator object in java debugger

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, foreach

In the Intellij IDEA Java Debugger window, how can I show the implied iterator values and the collection for a for/each loop?

For example I made this simple loop through puppy names. I want to be able to see in the debugger window where my index is for the loop and be able to see the collection that I'm looping through.

That is, I want to know what index I'm at. Like for "milo", I want to know that I'm at index 0. Older versions of IDEA used to have a variable like "i$" in the debugger variable display. And it would have a variable, I'm pretty sure, for the collection itself. I'm using the latest version, 14.0.3, on Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.2 (JDK 1.8 build 25 from Oracle).

Obviously this is a simple example that I've constructed solely for explaining my question.

[image: loop example]

Here is my debugger settings menu

[image: debugger settings]

Comment: Maybe I'm confused.  The debugger in 14 is showing you what the current value of the iterator is for each iteration of the loop.  What other information did you need?

Comment: Yeah, it's a simple example. Perhaps too simple. I want to know what index I'm at, like for "milo" I'm at index 0. Older versions of IDEA used to have a variable like "i$" in the debugger variable display. And it would have one, I'm pretty sure, for the collection itself. I've updated my question

Comment: In my setup, the `i$` variable is still there.  I do stress though that it's less vital right now since you shouldn't really care what position you are in the iterator (especially since you're iterating over *everything*), but you *do* want to know what value it's currently got - which is what the text to the right of the code is doing.

Comment: Ok, can I come over and use your IntelliJ?

Comment: It might be a bit of a drive, to be honest...in either event, I'm not entirely sure why your debugger isn't showing those values.  Check around the "Customize Data Views" window to see what options you have selected.

Comment: _Ok, can I come over and use your IntelliJ?_ – best SO comment ever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contacted JetBrains support. They say that this is a bug, or not a supported feature, in the Oracle JDK 8 for Mac. They have filed a service request with Oracle.

For others who have a different JDK that supports the generated loop variables and you are looking for the control of how to turn the display of the generated loop control variables on or off, see [Scott Woodward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2183755/scott-woodward)'s excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28636157/266531).

Answer (score 2):

Under the debugger settings, there's an option called "auto-variables mode" or "all-variables mode" (depending on which way its set). For me, toggling that hid/showed the `$i` variable. The settings menu is located down low where the debugger's resume button is.

On my system, when the text displayed in the menu is "Auto-Variables Mode" is when I have the `i$` variable.

Comment: This is the one.  I was looking for this to see why it was showing for me, but not for Kirby.  Good find.

Comment: This is what I recalled, too. In this version, I don't know why, I don't have that option. I've been pulling my ever thinning hairs out trying to find it again.

Comment: I'm on the same version as you, using Windows however. What options are available under the debug settings menu? (if you even have it, since I don't see if in your screenshot).

Comment: Does not work for me.  Latest version too, on Windows.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I've added a snapshot of my debugger settings. I've also asked JetBrains.

Comment: The all-variables mode is there, toggle it to the other setting auto-variables mode. It's a bit sneaky how it changes names, I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yup, I tried that before posting my question. It has no effect.

Comment: That's odd, for me, toggling it will hide/show the args and i$ variables (which are blue when displayed), leaving my puppy and puppies (which are reddish and always displayed).

Comment: yeah, it's driving me crazy

Comment: Possible workaround: try adding a watch for i$. Displays it for me even when its hidden from the variables pane. Not ideal, but could help in the mean time.

Comment: Did some more testing of this stuff. I was able to modify various variables by changing compilers (settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler) The version I had by default was to use javac, with Generate Debugging Info on, which was the default, so not sure if it will help. jdk 1.6 and 1.7 tested.

Comment: I think that you're last comment here is the issue, Scott. Thank you. I've contacted JetBrains Support and they concur. I'm using JDK 1.8 from Oracle. No solution, yet, though.